# Indexing along a line of 3 D array

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Consider a line joining two point X(a, b, c) and Y(d, e, f)in a 3 dimension array. How to find indices of all points in between them along the line, except Least square?

Answer (score 1):

You should *definitely* stay away from least squares, which would browse the entire 3D space if I understood you correclty. Instead, have a look at [Bresenheim's Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Basically you start with the starting cube, compute the line's gradient in each XYZ direction, and start marching.

You alternate marching in X (for example) direction until the line is no longer inside the cube, then you switch to whichever other direction (Y, Z) brings the line back into the current cube. And so on an so forth until the current cube is the target.

All usual links are in 2D, but the process in 3D is exactly the same.

The trickier bits resides in choosing which direction to start matching. There's an algo in 3D, which whould be adapted to 2D.

**Notes:**
*A cool optimization is, each time you march in a given direction, you can march Nx, or Ny, or Nz steps straight. these 3 numbers can be computed before hand and will never change.*

*A cooler optimization, is, you should only have to compute the order of X-Y-Z iteration (which might well be Y,X,Z in some cases) only once, at the beginning. Then the marching is nicely periodic and should stay the same until the target is reached.*